# Explore the absolute convergence of the series with alternating sign

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the best solution for assigning this series for `Absolute convergence` or `Conditional convergence`?

I think that we can divide this Summation to two Summations: with positive and with negative sign.

Series:
 \begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n*{\frac{arcctg(n)}{\sqrt{n}}}
  \end{eqnarray}

Comment: "Best" in what sense ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean the shortest solution, which can be very obviously

Comment: The series of the absolute values of the terms can be compared to $\sum_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @logarithm: no, this is inconclusive.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you don't know what you are talking about, then [learn it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: @logarithm: I appreciate your condescension, but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
 {\frac{\text{arccot}(n)}{\sqrt{n}}}\sim\frac1{n^{3/2}},
$$
absolute.

Comment: I respect your answer, but can you describe it a bit?

Comment: @EgorRandomize: no, that would make the answer suboptimal.

Comment: Okay, I understood that you mean that we can divide series to two absolute series. This way, sum of two abs. series is abs. series?

Comment: @EgorRandomize: there are no signs in the absolute series.

Comment: Please, describe this transformation, because it was so quickly, that I lost my connection with every math formulas

Comment: Coz it is too unobviously, I can't fully understand the transformation. Is arccot(n)  equals to 1/n?

Comment: @EgorRandomize: yes, asymptotically. This is what $\sim$ means.